# How to show Plank dock in front of maximised windows?

Tags: plank

Is it possible to keep the Plank dock in front of maximised windows? I checked the Preferences menu but could not find the right combination of settings to let the dock appear in front of maximised windows without having the windows to be shrinked to not overlay with the dock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Plank doesn't offer a hide mode that will always overlap maximized windows.